# String splitting into words in masm

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32, irvine32

I am trying to split a string into words & check the frequency of words in the string.

The problem is that when I try to split the string using "Space" as delimiter the first word is stored in the new array and after that the string is not copied to the next string.

Here is the code what I did so far This program takes a string as input and print the number of occurance of the word.

```
    INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
    .data
;declaring the variables for processign 
       aString BYTE ?
       singleWords BYTE 51 DUP (?)
       indexArray BYTE 51 DUP (?)
       counterArray BYTE 51 DUP (?)
       wordIndex BYTE ?
       counterIndex BYTE ?
       mycount BYTE ?

    .code

    main PROC

; Providing offset of the aString variable where the string will be save after  ; the readString method is called

       mov  edx, OFFSET aString
       mov  ecx, 50            ;buffer size - 1
       call ReadString

; making the counter 0 for loop 
; and then passing the length of the string for processing
; wordIndex is used to save the index where the space occur to later on loop
; through that much characters in singleWords array
; counter index is just for checking the loop is working 
       mov ecx, 0
       mov esi, 0
       mov edi, 0
       mov wordIndex, 0
       mov counterIndex, 0
       mov mycount, 0

       mov ecx, eax
       Loop1:
            CMP ecx, 0 ;compare if the string is empty so stop the loop
            JE L03
            mov al, aString[esi] ;passing the characters to al for space      ;checking
            CMP al, 32
            JE L01

            mov singleWords[esi], al ; if not space then copy the character to ;singleWords array
            INC esi
            INC mycount
            INC wordIndex
            DEC ecx
            JMP Loop1
        L01:
            mov bl, wordIndex ; if sapce occur pass the index to bl
            mov indexArray[edi], bl ; save the index in indexArray
            INC edi
            INC esi
            INC mycount
            INC wordIndex
            DEC ecx
            JMP Loop1
        L03:
            mov edx,OFFSET singleWords 
            call Writestring

            movzx eax, mycount
            call WriteDec

       call Crlf
       exit
       main ENDP
    END main
```

Comment: Can you put comments and use meaningful label names? That would really help us understand your code faster, and thus help you faster.

Comment: comments are added so check it out now :p

Comment: @ArifKhan I formatted the whole block as code even if that now means a bad indentation. You may want to fix that and check the effect of your edits.

Comment: Can you explain the data structures you planned to use? Particularly are you marking the words in-place? Or extracting the words for later to count them? The code seem very incomplete.

Comment: yeah i have coded it this far basically i want to store the words and then check the occurrence (frequency) of each word not character that how many times each word is there in the string any suggestion will be appreciated :)

Comment: @MargaretBloom Thank you for your editing I really appreciate it :)

Comment: Your main loop works for me.